# Is it safe to drive with this scratched wheel or should I fix it?

Tags: tires, car, wheels

This is the scratched wheel after hitting a big rock is it safe to drive?Is it a scratch or a crack?[image]

Comment: While that looks fairly insignificant, you would be best taking it to a wheel specialist for them to look for any cracks in person.

Comment: As well as to see if it is still true or out of round. We can't do that for you here on the internet.

Comment: Short of visiting a wheel shop, some ways of damage assessment may be asking yourself the following questions? Does the car vibrate at any speed since hitting that rock? Any steering wheel feedback (front wheel/suspension damage)? Tire pressure leak? Updated TPMS; individual tire pressures can be very helpful if pressures are monitored at least once a week unless totally ignored then a tire pressure gauge is needed to determine if damage was sufficient to cause bead separation for a leak to occur. At the least, damage allows bare aluminum to begin corrosion that can lead to a bead leak later.

Comment: It dosent have tire pressure leak, it shows on computer

Comment: The sidewall of the tire appears to be damaged.  I wouldn't drive on that tire at all.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Alloy wheels won't lose their round. They just simply do not bend. They crack. But it takes *a ton* of force to crack them. There's no way that little scratch event made a crack.

Comment: @End What sidewall damage? There is none...

Comment: @58368 - Tell that to my the wheels on my daughter's Honda Fit she used to own. Not only can alloy wheels lose their round, they can bend, too. I've personally seen several which could fit into either category.

Comment: That's just a little scratch. The tire actually wraps down behind the rim by more than an inch, and sometimes more than two inches. There is absolutely no increased risk of the tire losing it's seating on the wheel. Combined with the knowledge that there is no leaking, just carry on and be more careful next time. The tire looks unaffected as well.